# Item rows duplicate and SUM for Total Expense

Tags: sql, ms-access

When the below query is executed the "TotalExpense" column duplicates to the number of rows that are present in the tblOrderProduct for a given SalesID.

```
SELECT ItemSales.OrderDate,tblExpense.DateOfExpense ,(Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice))) AS TotalSales, (Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense))) AS TotalExpense , (Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice)) - Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense)))AS Profit
FROM (ItemSales 
LEFT JOIN tblOrderProduct ON ItemSales.SalesID = tblOrderProduct.SalesID)
LEFT JOIN tblExpense ON itemSales.OrderDate = tblExpense.DateOfExpense
GROUP BY ItemSales.OrderDate, tblExpense.DateOfExpense
ORDER BY ItemSales.OrderDate

UNION SELECT ItemSales.OrderDate, tblExpense.DateOfExpense, (Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice))) AS TotalSales, (Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense))) AS TotalExpense ,(Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice)) - Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense)))AS Profit
FROM (ItemSales
RIGHT JOIN tblExpense ON ItemSales.OrderDate = tblExpense.DateOfExpense)
LEFT JOIN tblOrderProduct ON ItemSales.SalesID = tblOrderProduct.SalesID
GROUP BY ItemSales.OrderDate,tblExpense.DateOfExpense
ORDER BY ItemSales.OrderDate
```

EDIT :-

Please see below for the result I get from the executed query:
[image]

The value highlighted in red only has expense worth 1000 for the given date, How ever the sales related to the same day has 22 rows of data hence the result is showing 22000

What is causing this duplication?

Comment: What is this query supposed to be doing?  Without data, it might be hard to answer your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the questions as per your request

Answer (score 0):

```html
 SELECT ItemSales.OrderDate,tblExpense.DateOfExpense ,(Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice))) AS TotalSales, (Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense))) AS TotalExpense , (Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice)) - Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense)))AS Profit
FROM (ItemSales 
LEFT JOIN tblOrderProduct ON ItemSales.SalesID = tblOrderProduct.SalesID)

LEFT JOIN
( select DateOfExpense,sum(Expense) AS Expense FROM tblExpense  Group by  DateOfExpense)
 tblExpense ON itemSales.OrderDate = tblExpense.DateOfExpense

GROUP BY ItemSales.OrderDate, tblExpense.DateOfExpense
ORDER BY ItemSales.OrderDate

UNION 

SELECT ItemSales.OrderDate, tblExpense.DateOfExpense, (Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice))) AS TotalSales, (Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense))) AS TotalExpense ,(Nz(SUM(tblOrderProduct.Quantity * tblOrderProduct.ConsumerPrice)) - Nz(SUM(tblExpense.Expense)))AS Profit
FROM ItemSales

RIGHT JOIN 
( select DateOfExpense,sum(Expense) AS Expense FROM tblExpense  Group by  DateOfExpense)
 tblExpense ON ItemSales.OrderDate = tblExpense.DateOfExpense

LEFT JOIN tblOrderProduct ON ItemSales.SalesID = tblOrderProduct.SalesID
GROUP BY ItemSales.OrderDate,tblExpense.DateOfExpense
ORDER BY ItemSales.OrderDate
```

Comment: I get the following error
_Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression'ItemSales.orderDate = tblExpense.DateOfExpense'
LEFT JOIN tblOrderProduct ON ItemSalesID = tblOrderProduct.SalesID'_